# Where to keep big SQL test scripts for database integration testing?

Tags: sql, database, integration-testing

In my project, a DB integration test is a big SQL script with several complex SQL statements. Now it is executed manually by a tester.

I am thinking how to run it automatically and as part of Continuous Deployment.

My approach is as follows:

1. Store the script as a SQL stored procedure in a dedicated AutoTestData database.
2. Have a C# test script which will call the above stored procedure.

I see the following *benefit* in this approach:

Given the size and complexity of such SQL scripts, it is easier to create and maintain them in their native environment, in a SQL database.

So, when a DB developer creates such a SQL script, he does not need to transform it to a different format, e.g. for a unit testing framework, like DbUnit.

The *disadvantage* of this approach is that I split a test into 2 parts: a SQL stored procedure and a C# test script. Thus I keep the scripts in two different projects and deploy them in differently.

*Are there any better approaches for integration testing with big SQL scripts?*

Comment: Are these scripts part of the production system or purely for testing purposes? If they are just for testing then I would consider keeping them outside the database under version control.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkWagoner. Yes, the complex SQL scripts are just for testing. I like your idea and feel it will work.